# MySQL update with inner join

Tags: mysql, triggers, set, inner-join, outer-join

I have 3 tables, products, warehouse and order details. When customer places order, it places one (or several) productIDs into order details table. What i'm trying to do is reduce quantity for that product in my warehouse table by trigger. I've come up to this query which selects this particular number which needs to be reduced by one, however, i can not turn it into update. I've tried lots of variations, but none seem to work since i can't use (SELECT**** inside where when using UPDATE)

```
SELECT warehouse.kolicina
FROM warehouse
INNER JOIN order_details ON warehouse.productID = order_details.productID
WHERE warehouse.productID = (
SELECT order_details.productID
FROM order_details
LEFT OUTER JOIN warehouse ON ( warehouse.productID = order_details.productID )
ORDER BY order_details.orderID DESC
```

So basically what i want to do is

```
after each insert on table order_details
UPDATE warehouse
SET quantity = quantity - 1
where warehouse.productID = last productID from table order_details
```

If anyone has idea how to make it work, i would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You would create an after update trigger and do the update there.  The full code would look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER order_details_trigger AFTER INSERT ON order_details
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE warehouse
        SET quantity = quantity - 1
        where warehouse.productID = new.productID;
END;
```

|

Comment: No luck, i'm getting syntax error. What does this new.productID return, last entry in order_details?

Comment: @user3118994 . . . It is from the record that was inserted.